# Scraping Bitchute, question about POST method

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have used the Inspect Mode of the Firefox browser, to see what material the Bitchute website Sends.

Under the Network Tab, I see a POST method, giving this URL under the File tab: https://www.bitchute.com/api/search/list/

The content is a JSON object with all the search results.

I wonder if there is an easy way to access this JSON object with the request library. I personally simply have no idea how to do it, cannot present sample code.

Edit, some sample code, made with the help of ChatGPT, I used cURL to diagnose what is wrong; some CSRF verification fails.

```
import requests

# Set the search query and other parameters
search_query = "12 monkeys"
sort_by = "relevance"
page = 0

# Set the URL and headers for the POST request
url = "https://www.bitchute.com/api/search/list/"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3",
    "Referer": "https://www.bitchute.com"
}

# Send a GET request to obtain the CSRF token
response = requests.get("https://www.bitchute.com")
csrf_token = response.cookies.get_dict().get("csrftoken")

# Set the JSON payload for the POST request, including the CSRF token
payload = {
    "query": search_query,
    "sort_by": sort_by,
    "page": page,
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token
}

# Send the POST request and get the response
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out now.

Here's the updated code:

```
import requests
from json import loads
# Set the search query and other parameters
search_query = "monkeys"
sort_by = "relevance"
page = 0

# Set the URL and headers for the POST request
url = "https://www.bitchute.com/api/search/list/"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "www.bitchute.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.bitchute.com",
    "Referer": f"https://www.bitchute.com/search/?query={search_query}",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3",
}

# Open a session and get the CSRF middleware token
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(f"https://www.bitchute.com/search/?query={search_query}")
index1 = response.text.index("csrf") + 28
csrf_token = response.text[index1:index1+64]

# Set the payload for the POST request
payload = {
    "query": search_query,
    "sort_by": sort_by,
    "page": page,
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token,
}

# Send the POST request and get the response
response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).content.decode()

for element in loads(response)["results"]:
    print(element["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the POST method better, I would still really appreciate an answer if anybody knows one.
Until that time, I came to the conclusion that one can just use google to scrape any website. I already had a script scraping google, so I just made a minor edit to make it only search Bitchute. Works like a charm, just some minor beauty details I could improve in the future:

```
def search_bc(self, search_terms):
    encoded_search = quote_plus(search_terms)
    url = f"https://www.google.nl/search?q={encoded_search}+site%3Abitchute.com/video&start=0&num=40"
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    try:        
        line = request(url, timeout=10, headers=headers,cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20210328-17-p0.en-GB+FX+{}'.format(randint(100, 999))}).text
    except:
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line, "html.parser")
    output = {}
    for result in soup.find_all('a',href = True): 
        x = result.text
        
        if " › " in x and not "youtube" in x:
            try:
                title = result.find("h3").text[:-11]
                if "Channel Blocked" in title:
                    continue
                description = x[len(title):]
                url=unquote(result["href"].split("url=")[1].split("&ved=")[0])
                output[title]={"title": title,"description":description,"url": url}
            except:
                pass

    return output
```